# how to set http headers using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to get data from an api. Output to text for now.
The api does not accept standard authentication the headers must contain 2 fields
username=12345
password=12345
Can someone post a simple javascript to do this?

Comment: Here is a [getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) on Ajax.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson where in that guide is mentioned how to set userID and password on an ajax request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax) which was EASILY found googling for `userid password ajax`

Comment: @mplungjan It is not mentioned explicitly, but Step 1 explain how to set the headers - adopting that to this case would give something like `httpRequest.setRequestHeader('username', '12345');`

Comment: Ah - right. missed that. Was looking for auth.